Four-acceleration and the equivalence principle
I was reading the last part this answer by John Rennie, and I am bit confused about magnitude of each component of 4-acceleration when standing on the surface of the Earth compared to standing in an elevator accelerating upwards in outer space by $g$. I want to check if I understood correctly.
In both situations, (assume the origin of the inertia reference frame is on the surface with positive $z$-axis oriented radially outward) the z-component of the 4-acceleration is
$$A^3=A_\text{SR}^3+A_\text{GR}^3=g$$
right?
When you're at rest on the Earth, $A_\text{SR}^3=0$ and $A_\text{GR}^3=g$. On the other hand, if you're at rest in an accelerating elevator, $A_\text{SR}^3=g$ and $A_\text{GR}^3=0$?
What about other components $A^0, A^1, A^2$? Are they all zero?
On a related note, the comments to the answer of the recent question of mine gave me some food for thought. In particular, I learned that the one reason why the components 4-acceleration vanish during free fall on Earth is because
$$A^\lambda=\frac{dU^\lambda }{d\tau } + \Gamma^\lambda {}_{\mu \nu}U^\mu U^\nu=-g+g=0$$
I wonder if it is true for $\lambda=3$ (z-component) only? For other components $\lambda=0,1,2$: $$\frac{dU^\lambda }{d\tau }=\Gamma^\lambda {}_{\mu \nu}U^\mu U^\nu=0$$ right?

Yes, all of the other components of the four-acceleration are 0 in both cases. See the Catalogue of Spacetimes.
Section 2.1.6 describes accelerating coordinates in flat spacetime. Here they use $(\rho,y,z)$ for the spatial coordinates with the acceleration in the $\rho$ direction. Note that the Christoffel symbols involving $y$ and $z$ are all $0$.
Section 2.2.1 describes the usual coordinates in a spherically symmetric spacetime. Here the acceleration is in the $r$ direction. The Christoffel symbols involving the other directions are not all zero, so it isn't as clear as the previous case. However, note that only the $r$ direction has any Christoffel symbols with time $t$. So the Christoffel symbols involving the other directions are not related to fictitious forces but rather to the spherical instead of Cartesian spatial coordinates.

Thanks. To be clear, by "yes" you mean everything I said in the question is correct?

@user366875 sorry, that was indeed unclear. I have clarified in the answer itself

@Dale Note that OP has asked in his post about two "four accelerations": 1. The proper four acceleration $A^{\lambda}$ in his post 2. The coordinate four acceleration $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}U^{\lambda}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$, as mentioned in OP's last written sentences.  I think the latter doesn't necessarily vanish, e.g. in particular $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}U^0}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$ is what's responsible to gravitational time dilation. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

.. ok, unless it's a typo and he meant to write a $+$ instead of a $=$ in that last equation ;) I didn't consider it when writing the above comment.

@Amit There is only one four acceleration. What you describe as the coordinate four acceleration is not a terminology I have ever seen before and not a terminology that I would use or introduce in my answer. The time component does vanish. The time dilation is constant so its derivative is 0
